# Remove/Install windows services using batch

Tags: tomcat, service, batch-file, cmd

I've got a service called `serv1` which I don't know it's state (already installed or not), this service gets installed via another batch file (`service.bat install`)

My goal is to write a `.bat` file which checks if `serv1` exists, so I want to **remove** it and **re-create** it calling '`service.bat install`' ; if not, create it calling '`service.bat install`'

I've searched for some commands; I found that we use " `sc delete ServiceName` but, I'm not familiar with batch a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope the following bat script will help you out. Open notepad; copy the following code and paste it in notepad. Save the file with .bat extension e.g. "Helper.bat".

Now open command prompt, navigate to the directory where Helper.bat (and your service.bat) are placed. Then write a command like this
    Helper.bat serv1

This is a generic script so you need to pass the concerned service name as a parameter. Otherwise simply replace **%1** with **serv1** and get your work done!

If you need to know more about this script then feel free to ask me.

Here's the script:

```
@echo off
sc query %1
IF ERRORLEVEL == 1060 GOTO NOT_EXIST

:Exist
    cls
    echo %1 already exist.
    SET /P result=Do you want to delete and reinstall the service? (Press Y or N)

    IF %result% == Y
            GOTO REINSTALL_SERVICE

    IF %result% == N
            GOTO End

GOTO End

:NOT_EXIST
    cls
    echo Service does not exist. Going to install now
    GOTO INSTALL_SERVICE

:REINSTALL_SERVICE
    sc delete %1
    GOTO INSTALL_SERVICE

:INSTALL_SERVICE:
    call service.bat install
    echo Installation Completed!

:End
    pause
```